# Sort a PHP array by another array order and date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Was wondering if there is a way to sort (usort or equiv) an array based on key order of another array and date. I know how to do basic date sorting with usort, but was wondering if you could do both in one shot.

```
$cats = array(1,6,3,4,7,2);
$prods = array(
 array('cat'=>1,'date'=>'1/3/2011'),
 array('cat'=>2,'date'=>'1/6/2011'),
 array('cat'=>3,'date'=>'2/3/2011')
);
```

I want $prods sorted by the category order of $cats and date order of $prods

Comment: You may have to tweak your data structures a bit, but you should be able to accomplish this with [`array_multisort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: I can't understand what kind of sort you need, and by the way that's not even valid code

Comment: I assume the ids are not unique in arr2?

Comment: @MatteoRiva what part isn't valid code? I want $arr2 sorted first to match the order of $arr1 and then sorted by the dates of $arr2 (ASC).

Comment: @tandu Correct, it would probably be clearer if they were category IDs

Comment: ive read it 5 times and still dont understand what End Array should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to your low accept rate, as it can deter people from taking the time to answer your questions. Remember to mark valid answers as accepted or otherwise post a comment to them explaining why they aren't valid.

This solution works fine in php 5.3+, if you are trapped in an older version you can easily replace DateTime objects with calls to [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php).

Products with a category that has no position specified are pushed to the end of the list (see product with cat == 42 in the example).

```
$cats = array(1,6,3,4,7,2);

// added a few products to test the date sorting
$prods = array(
  array('cat'=>1,'date'=>'3/3/2011'),
  array('cat'=>1,'date'=>'2/3/2011'),
  array('cat'=>1,'date'=>'1/3/2011'),
  array('cat'=>42,'date'=>'2/3/2011'),
  array('cat'=>2,'date'=>'1/3/2011'),
  array('cat'=>2,'date'=>'2/3/2011'),
  array('cat'=>2,'date'=>'1/6/2011'),
  array('cat'=>3,'date'=>'2/3/2011')
);

// need an index of category_id => position wanted in the sort
$r_cats = array_flip($cats);
// if the category of a product is not found in the requested sort, we will use 0, and product with category id 0 will be sent to the end of the sort
$r_cats[0] = count($r_cats);
// this one is needed for DateTime, put whatever your timezone is (not important for the use we do of it, but required to avoid a warning)
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

usort($prods, function($a, $b) use($r_cats) {
  $cat_a = isset($r_cats[$a['cat']]) ? $r_cats[$a['cat']] : $r_cats[0];
  $cat_b = isset($r_cats[$b['cat']]) ? $r_cats[$b['cat']] : $r_cats[0];

  if ($cat_a < $cat_b) {
    return -1;
  } elseif ($cat_a > $cat_b) {
    return 1;
  }

  $date_a = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y', $a['date']);
  $date_b = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y', $b['date']);

  if ($date_a < $date_b) {
    return -1;
  } elseif ($date_a > $date_b) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
});

var_dump($prods);
```

The results are as follow:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(1)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "1/3/2011"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(1)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "2/3/2011"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(1)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "3/3/2011"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(3)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "2/3/2011"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(2)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "1/3/2011"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(2)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "2/3/2011"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(2)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "1/6/2011"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(42)
    ["date"]=>
    string(8) "2/3/2011"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lepidosteus. I'm working on improving on taking the time to respond to posters. I'm on < 5.3, but I get what you're doing here and was able to make it work.